# How to extract a certain amount of char from a long string until the end of the string

Tags: c#, arrays, substring, trim

Lets say I have the following string:

> 1111000011001101

How can I extract substrings of 4 chars until the end of the string so that I have the following array ?

```
|1111|0000|1100|1101|
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Strings are only char[]'s you can use the [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)(int a, int b) method to retrieve the number of characters specified (int b) from a character position in the string (int a).

If you wanted the first four characters of your string you could use

```
String s = "1111000011001101";
String firstFourChars = s.Substring(0,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with LinqPad I get the following:

```
var s = "1111000011001101";

var substrings = Enumerable
  .Range(0, s.Length / 4)
  .Select(i => s.Substring(i * 4, 4))
  .ToArray();

substrings.Dump();
```

Output:

```
String[] (4 items)
1111 
0000 

1100 
1101
```

EDIT: Just noticed this is a duplicate of answer -- see link in the comments of OP. See that link as it gives a general solution.